# Get access to Thumb/Handle/Knob of Swing's JSlider

Tags: java, swing, handle, jslider

Basically I want to display the current value pointed to by the slider handle when in motion (either via mouse or keyboard). I can easily get the current value by adding a new ChangeListener & overriding stateChanged  method. But I cant seem to get the current location of the handle.

I can just bite the bullet and create a label at a constant place & update it continuously but I want to display the value just above (or below) the handle.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? While there's no direct api to get the thumbPosition, you can calculate (at least approximately) by simple geometry ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an good or very flexible solution but maybe you can implement your own `SliderUI`. E.g. using the already defined `BasicUI` you can access the field `thumbRect` which contains the values you need.

```
slider.setUI(new BasicSliderUI(slider) {
  public void paintThumb(Graphics g) {
    super.paintThumb(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString(Integer.toString(slider.getValue()), thumbRect.x, thumbRect.y + thumbRect.height);
  }
});
```

Comment: possible, but typically not a good idea - maintain several (one per LAF) ui implementations over jdk versions is not exactly fun ;-)

Comment: So now there is a new problem. I get the values of thumb alright but when I try to set the location of JLabel that shows current value, it starts jumping all over the place & produces a flickering effect.

Comment: @Chantz - jumping when doing what exactly? Time for a short runnable (blabla) code example

Comment: @kleopatra sorry for the delayed response. Actually I ended up junking the feature. Although I will try to come up with SSCCE ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

If the [*Nimbus Look and Feel*](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/swingset3_nimbus_and_java_se) is an option, a live display of the value can be specified in the relevant UI default:

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Slider.paintValue", true);
```

Comment: was wondering why the property had to be added to the LAFDefaults - should work as well with a simple UIManager.put - looks like a bug that's fixed in 1.7 (so there _had_ been bug fixes to Nimbus ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra: Thanks for addressing this; I modified the defaults empirically, without really understanding why `UIManager.put()` failed. Is [this](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6653395) the bug?

Comment: don't know - simply noticed that putting to lookandfeelDefaultswas necessary in 1.6 and UIManager.put suffised in 1.7